# How should I make the relation work in this Database model

Tags: database, model, relational-database, visio

(I apologies in advance for my English)
I need to make a model of relation.

Normally it a thing we should do in team, but I am stuck to be alone, so I am kind of overwhelm by this

It about a school and it information concerning The Student, The Parents and the Class he want to enroll. Also they keep academic results.

I just can't get an ideal of how I could link them all and avoiding relations problems

https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ZiKn.jpg

Comment: Are you having difficulty with modeling family relations or understanding logical database relations?

Comment: A little bit of everything. But right now I just don't see what should I add in the tables and how to link them all so they fit together without causing an "infinite relation"

Comment: What do you mean by an "infinite relation"?

Answer (score 0):

First, I suggest you add a Person table to supertype Parent and Student, and move all the personal and contact information attributes to Person.  You're sure to want to add additional information later, and having to duplicate everything for parents, students (and later, teachers and other school staff) gets to be a nuisance.

```
person (person_id PK, last_name, first_name, sex, birthday, email, address, city, phone_number, cellphone_number)
```

Next, do you want to record biological parents or caregivers?  In schools we normally care about caregivers and their relationship to the student.  To record that, you could create a relationship type table:

```
relationship (relationship_id PK, description)
```

with entries for father, mother, aunt, grandfather, fostermother, etc.  You can then record the relationship between 2 persons like so:

```
parent (parent_id PK/FK, child_id PK/FK, relationship FK)
```

If you wanted to record biological parents, you could use:

```
bioparents (child_id PK/FK, father_id FK, mother_id FK)
```

with father and mother ids nullable (or decompose into separate tables for father and mother) since we're unlikely to know both parents for all students.

Finally, we get to the business at hand, students.  Historical information and alumni are important in schools, so take care to model students over time, not just current students.  You need to consider the time resolution for student registrations - are registrations annual, quarterly, or something else?  For annual registrations, you could start with:

```
student (person_id PK/FK, year)
```

Now, what is a class?  Is it something that recurs over time, or are classes with the same name in different years/quarters separate things?  Can classes contain learners of different forms/grades/levels, or are they partitions of those?  Is a class a grouping of students that attend multiple subjects, or a subject-specific grouping?  I'm familiar with two types of classes, which could be called form classes and academic classes, but things may be different in your region of the world.

Using your class table:

```
class (class_number PK, name, prerequisite, formation_time)
```

We need to link students to it.  If class membership is an annual thing, we can add to the student relation above, e.g.

```
student (person_id PK/FK, year, class_number FK)
```

Now, I just made up tables as I went along, but if you want to do this properly, you really should list/model your functional dependencies before you start making up tables.  You could look into a formal modeling discipline like Object-Role Modeling, or at least write out simple logical relations in both directions:

```
a Student has one or more Parents
a Parent has one or more Students

a Class has a Year
a Year has zero or more Classes

a Student has a Class per Year
```

For non-binary relations, you don't need to write it out in every direction, but you do need to decide which combinations of attributes uniquely determine the others.  For example, the combination of Student and Year uniquely determines the Class.

Anyway, that should give you a start.